# Why no eval plot for this DNN binary classifier tf.estimator model in tensorboard?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I'm using `tf.estimator` API with TensorFlow 1.13 on Google AI Platform to build a DNN Binary Classifier.  For some reason I don't get a `eval` graph but I do get a `training` graph.

Here are two different methods for performing training.  The first is the normal python method and the second is using GCP AI Platform in local mode.

Notice in either method, the evaluation is simply a dot for what appears to be the final result.  I was expecting a plot similar to training where it would be a curve.

Lastly, I show the relevant model code for the performance metric.

**Normal python notebook method:**

[image]

```
%%bash
#echo ${PYTHONPATH}:${PWD}/${MODEL_NAME}
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${PWD}/${MODEL_NAME}
python -m trainer.task \
   --train_data_paths="${PWD}/samples/train_sounds*" \
   --eval_data_paths=${PWD}/samples/valid_sounds.csv  \
   --output_dir=${PWD}/${TRAINING_DIR} \
   --hidden_units="175" \
   --train_steps=5000 --job-dir=./tmp
```

**Local gcloud (GCP) ai-platform method:**

[image]

```
%%bash

OUTPUT_DIR=${PWD}/${TRAINING_DIR}



echo "OUTPUT_DIR=${OUTPUT_DIR}"
echo "train_data_paths=${PWD}/${TRAINING_DATA_DIR}/train_sounds*"



gcloud ai-platform local train \
   --module-name=trainer.task \
   --package-path=${PWD}/${MODEL_NAME}/trainer \
   -- \
   --train_data_paths="${PWD}/${TRAINING_DATA_DIR}/train_sounds*" \
   --eval_data_paths=${PWD}/${TRAINING_DATA_DIR}/valid_sounds.csv  \
   --hidden_units="175" \
   --train_steps=5000 \
   --output_dir=${OUTPUT_DIR}
```

**The performance metric code**

```
estimator = tf.contrib.estimator.add_metrics(estimator, my_auc)
```

And

```
# This is from the tensorflow website for adding metrics for a DNNClassifier
# https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/auc
def my_auc(features, labels, predictions):
    return {
        #'auc': tf.metrics.auc( labels, predictions['logistic'], weights=features['weight'])
        #'auc': tf.metrics.auc( labels, predictions['logistic'], weights=features[LABEL])
#        'auc': tf.metrics.auc( labels, predictions['logistic'])
        'auc': tf.metrics.auc( labels, predictions['class_ids']),
        'accuracy': tf.metrics.accuracy( labels, predictions['class_ids'])
    }
```

**The method used during train and evaluate**

```
   eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(
        input_fn = read_dataset(
            filename = args['eval_data_paths'],
            mode = tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL,
            batch_size = args['eval_batch_size']),
        steps=100,
        throttle_secs=10,   
        exporters = exporter)


   # addition of throttle_secs=10 above and this
   # below as a result of one of the suggested answers.
   # The result is that these mods do no print the final 
   # evaluation graph much less the intermediate results
   tf.estimator.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_steps=10)

   tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

**The DNN binary classifier using tf.estimator**

```
estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
                        model_dir = model_dir,
                        feature_columns = final_columns,
                        hidden_units=hidden_units,
                        n_classes=2)
```

**screenshot of file in model_trained/eval dir.**

Only this one file is in this directory. 
 It is named model_trained/eval/events.out.tfevents.1561296248.myhostname.local and looks like

[image]

Comment: How did you train the estimator?  Was it with `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate`?

Comment: Yes, I updated the question with my usage.

Comment: I added an answer below based upon your comments and suggestions as well as just playing with the parameters.  The results look to me like its not overfitting.  The eval loss is still trending downwards and has not started going up.  Which reminds me of a question.  In keras there is a method for early stopping based upon eval going up.  Is there such a method for estimators?  or, do you simply examine graph and modify the training steps based upon the eval loss going up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the comment and suggestions as well as tweaking the parameters, here is the result which works for me.

The code to start the tensorboard, train the model etc.  Using ------- to denote a notebook cell

---

```
%%bash
# clean model output dirs
# This is so that the trained model is deleted
output_dir=${PWD}/${TRAINING_DIR} 
echo ${output_dir}
rm -rf ${output_dir}
```

---

```
# start tensorboard
def tb(logdir="logs", port=6006, open_tab=True, sleep=2):
    import subprocess
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        "exec " + "tensorboard --logdir={0} --port={1}".format(logdir, port), shell=True)
    if open_tab:
        import time
        time.sleep(sleep)
        import webbrowser
        webbrowser.open("http://127.0.0.1:{}/".format(port))
    return proc


cwd = os.getcwd()
output_dir=cwd + '/' + TRAINING_DIR 
print(output_dir)


server1 = tb(logdir=output_dir)
```

---

```
%%bash
# The model run config is hard coded to checkpoint every 500 steps
#
#echo ${PYTHONPATH}:${PWD}/${MODEL_NAME}
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${PWD}/${MODEL_NAME}
python -m trainer.task \
   --train_data_paths="${PWD}/samples/train_sounds*" \
   --eval_data_paths=${PWD}/samples/valid_sounds.csv  \
   --output_dir=${PWD}/${TRAINING_DIR} \
   --hidden_units="175" \
   --train_batch_size=10 \
   --eval_batch_size=100 \
   --eval_steps=1000 \
   --min_eval_frequency=15 \
   --train_steps=20000 --job-dir=./tmp
```

The relevant model code

```
# This hard codes the checkpoints to be
# every 500 training steps?
estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
                    model_dir = model_dir,
                    feature_columns = final_columns,
                    hidden_units=hidden_units,
                    config=tf.estimator.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_steps=500),
                    n_classes=2)




# trainspec to tell the estimator how to get training data
train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(
    input_fn = read_dataset(
        filename = args['train_data_paths'],
        mode = tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN, # make sure you use the dataset api
        batch_size = args['train_batch_size']),
    max_steps = args['train_steps'])  # max_steps allows a resume

exporter = tf.estimator.LatestExporter(name = 'exporter',
                                       serving_input_receiver_fn = serving_input_fn)



eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(
    input_fn = read_dataset(
        filename = args['eval_data_paths'],
        mode = tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL,
        batch_size = args['eval_batch_size']),
    steps=args['eval_steps'],
    throttle_secs = args['min_eval_frequency'],
    exporters = exporter)




tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

The resultant graphs

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In `estimator.train_and_evaluate()` you specify a `train_spec` and an `eval_spec`. The `eval_spec` often has a different input function (e.g. development evaluation dataset, non-shuffled)

Every N steps, a checkpoint from the train process is saved, and the eval process loads those same weights and runs according to the `eval_spec`. Those eval summaries are logged under the step number of the checkpoint, so you are able to compare train vs test performance.

In your case, evaluation produces only a single point on the graph for each call to evaluate. This point contains the average over the entire evaluation call.
Take a look at [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18858) similar issue:

I would modify `tf.estimator.EvalSpec` with `throttle_secs` small value (Default is 600) and `save_checkpoints_steps` in `tf.estimator.RunConfig` to an small value as well:

`tf.estimator.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_steps=SOME_SMALL_VALUE_TO_VERIFY)`

[image]

Comment: I updated the code to show your suggestions.  Sadly it made it worse.  Now it does not show a final eval result for loss.

Comment: What happens now in your training and eval logs when you add a value only in `save_checkpoints_steps` ? do you see more than a point, please clarify.

Comment: Also what type of Estimator are you using? Thanks!

Comment: Ok for the first questions, do you mean remove the throttle_secs and keep the save_checkpoints_steps and afterwards see more than one point in the logs?  For the estimator type, its a dnn - binary classifier.

Comment: I'll update the original question with the estimator type.

Comment: With the code as shown above in my original question with your suggestions for save_checkpoints and throttle_secs addtions, I get a single file in the model_trained/eval/ directory.  Its a file which is ascii with a bunch of junk chars in it.  Linux file command says its a data file and not something it recognizes.  It looks like a combination ascii and binary.  I'll add a screenshot since I don't know how to interpet it.  BTW, is there a doc which describes this file?